# Python can't open myscript.py

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run my python program from cmd, but I have run into a problem. When I type `myscript.py` it gives my the error message:

`python: can't open file myscript.py:[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Help Much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Make sure you are in the right directory.

Comment: I suppose you are using windows, but you should make this extra clear and provide other necessary information such as which directory you are in and whether the file is in the same folder, etc.

Comment: You mistyped `myscript.py` (forgotten `c`).

Comment: From your description and your error message, it looks like you have a script called `myscript.py`, but you're trying to run it as `mysript.py`. If so, it's obviously not going to work, because there is no file called `mysript.py`.

Comment: 'mysript' is just a typo that I wrote in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely aren't in the same directory. Use the cd command to switch directories. You can type cd with no arguments to print your present working directory. Once you are in the same directory, you can run your python program. Alternatively, you can run python with the full path to your script.

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me the exact steps I need to take to do this, I am a bit of a noob.

Comment: I typed cd. It gave me the same directory and the same error.

Comment: Look where the file is in explorer, then cd to that directory. Then you can run the script.

Comment: Thank You! This has been nagging at me for a while.